# Website in APA style under "thebibliography" environment

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I am manually managing references by `thebibliography` environment  where  every item in the list starts with `\bibitem{bibkey}`. I am using APA style. I want to refer this website link in APA style: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/estimating-parameters-in-linear-mixed-effects-models.html, using `\bibitem{bibkey}`. How can I do that appropriately?

**EDIT:**

By APA style, I was looking for the format that Google Scholar uses. For example,

```
\begin{thebibliography}{30}

 \bibitem{Spit06} Spitzer, R. L., Kroenke, K., Williams, J. B., \& Löwe, B. (2006). A brief measure for assessing generalized anxiety disorder: the GAD-7. Archives of internal medicine, 166(10), 1092-1097.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide a manually formatted screenshot (e. g. using MS Word) of the desired output. In addition, it's more likely to get help when you provide a complete but yet minimal compile-able code.

Comment: There is no single, unique "APA style". Please be more specific as to what this term means to you.

Comment: If you use the manual `thebibliography` approach, then the entire bibliography formatting is up to you and you can choose whatever style you need. The question of how certain webpages should be cited in certain bibliography styles as such has nothing to do with (La)TeX and is generally off-topic here, but if you want APA style (7th.) edition have a look at https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/webpage-website-references, ...

Comment: ... you may end up with something like `\bibitem{mawo:lmem} MathWorks (n.d.) \emph{Estimating Parameters in Linear Mixed-Effects Models.} Retrieved September 9, 2020, from \url{https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/estimating-parameters-in-linear-mixed-effects-models.html}`

Comment: Depending on your field of study and the kind of document/work you are writing you may want to consider citing a more stable/traditional source like a well-liked textbook or a (survey) paper.